# RabbitMQ standalone version on windows

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

For some unit tests I have to write I would like to use a standalone version of RabbitMQ. What I have found so far is, that for Mac OS X there is a standalone version, means one with an included part of erlang so that nothing else has to be installed.

My questions:

Is there a similar way to achieve this in a windows / C# environment?

One alternative I see is that we can mock out some of the RabbitMQ access, which would be a more unit test approach. We can also point to an active test environment, but I don't really like this approach.,p.
The reason for having this connection is that we want to be able to make some performance tests with our own payloads which are in a 500k to 1000k size.

Comment: RabbitMQ Server is a service install, so unless you have a dedicated instance to yourself, load testing will be difficult. Hence my preference of ZeroMQ, cause it does not require a dedicated service to run.

Comment: Do you use Rabbitmq in production? Or do you need it just for test?

Comment: @Gas: I just need it for test purposes. We have an installation in production too but I'm not able to access it easily.

Comment: @Darek I was reading the following article: [link](http://videlalvaro.github.io/2013/04/using-rabbitmq-in-unit-tests.html) but obviously not careful enough. You are right I have to start RabbitMQ as service.

Comment: just to clarify, In windows you can execute rabbitmq also in command line, it not necessary install a service.

Comment: @Gas Do you have a link, which would demonstrate how we could start the server without installation? I could not find a proper bin for that. The other thought would be to have  a Docker or something similar, which could be started locally as a VM during test execution.

Comment: I take it back .. @Gas is right, YOU CAN run it from command line, but the process is not as straightforward as one would hope: http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html

Comment: So @BtD, use NUnit's TestFixtureSetup to spin up and TestFixtureTearDown to shut down an instance, using the above link's steps ... Or switch to ZeroMQ :)